# Bidiretional Graph in C with weighted arcs. Error while checking the input

Tags: c, graph, weighted, error-checking

I've made this program to create a weighted graph for university, but when I asks inputs in main, the output is not fixed; EX:. It doesn't insert a node, sometimes it doesn't find the error in input, or it keeps the same arc with different weights, which is what i want to avoid. There's no error in compilation, but the outputs are weird. Any suggestions on how to solve this? thanks:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Define a structure to represent a node in the graph
typedef struct node {
    int key;             // Index of the destination vertex
    int weight;
    struct node* next;    // Pointer to the next node in the adjacency list
} node_t;

// Define a structure to represent the graph
typedef struct graph {
    int V;            // Number of vertices in the graph
    node_t** adjList; // Array of pointers to the head of each adjacency list
} graph_t;

node_t* newNode(int dest);
graph_t* createGraph(int V);
void addEdge(graph_t* graph, int src, int key, int w);
void printGraph(graph_t* graph);
int isPresent(graph_t* g, int source, int key);

// Driver code to test the implementation
int main() {
    int nV = 0;
    printf("Insert number nV\n");
    scanf("%d", &nV);

    graph_t* graph = createGraph(nV);

    for(int i = 0; i < nV; i++)
    {
        int source = 0;
        int key = 0;
        int weight = 0;
        printf("Inert node, specify Source, Key and Weight [v:%d]: ", i);
        scanf("%d %d %d", &source, &key, &weight);

        while(source >= nV){
            printf("Source Out of Bounds, retry\n");
            scanf("%d", &source);
        }

        while(key >= nV){
            printf("Key Out of Bounds, retry\n");
            scanf("%d", &key);
        }

        while(isPresent(graph, source, key) == 1)
        {
            printf("Arc found, retry; new source, key:\n");
            scanf("%d %d", &source, &key);
        }

        printGraph(graph);
        addEdge(graph, source, key, weight);
    }
    printf("\nFinal Print\n");
    printGraph(graph);
    return 0;
}

// Function to create a new node with the given destination vertex index
node_t* newNode(int dest) {
    node_t* newNode = (node_t*) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    newNode->key = dest;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

// Function to create a new graph with the given number of vertices
graph_t* createGraph(int V) {
    graph_t* graph = (graph_t*) malloc(sizeof(graph_t));
    graph->V = V;
    graph->adjList = (node_t**) malloc(V * sizeof(node_t*));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < V; i++) {
        graph->adjList[i] = NULL;
    }
    return graph;
}

// Function to add an edge to the graph
void addEdge(graph_t* graph, int src, int key, int w) {
    // Add edge from src to key
    node_t* newN = newNode(key);
    newN->weight = w;
    newN->next = graph->adjList[src];
    graph->adjList[src] = newN;

    // Add edge from key to src (if the graph is undirected)
    node_t* newN2 = newNode(src);
    newN2->next = graph->adjList[key];
    newN2->weight = w;
    graph->adjList[key] = newN2;
}

int isPresent(graph_t* g1, int source, int key)
{
    graph_t* gTmp = g1;
    while(gTmp->adjList[source] != NULL)
    {
      if(gTmp->adjList[source]->key == key)
      {
          printf("Key in Common: %d\n", key);
          return 1;
      }
        gTmp->adjList[source] = gTmp->adjList[source]->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

// Function to print the adjacency list of the graph
void printGraph(graph_t* graph) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < graph->V; i++) {
        node_t* currNode = graph->adjList[i];
        printf("Adjacency list of vertex:\n");
        while (currNode != NULL) {
            printf(" %d --> %d - W: %d\n", i, currNode->key, currNode->weight);
            currNode = currNode->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

If the inputs are correct, I've no problems, while if they're wrong, the output is not fixed.

OUTPUT EXAMPLE:

```
Insert number nV
3
Inert node, specify Source, Key and Weight [v:0]: 0 1 55
Adjacency list of vertex:

Adjacency list of vertex:

Adjacency list of vertex:

Inert node, specify Source, Key and Weight [v:1]: 0 2 33

Adjacency list of vertex:

Adjacency list of vertex:
 1 --> 0 - W: 55

Adjacency list of vertex:

Inert node, specify Source, Key and Weight [v:2]: 0 1 44

Adjacency list of vertex:

Adjacency list of vertex:
 1 --> 0 - W: 55

Adjacency list of vertex:
 2 --> 0 - W: 33


**Final Print**

Adjacency list of vertex:
 0 --> 1 - W: 44

Adjacency list of vertex:
 1 --> 0 - W: 44
 1 --> 0 - W: 55

Adjacency list of vertex:
 2 --> 0 - W: 33


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. "gives some problems." What would that be? What input do you provide, what result do you expect, what do you get instead? Have you tried to run your code in a debugger and what was the outcome?

Comment: You should always check the return value of `scanf`. If you read a number but enter some invalid character, that will stay in input buffer if you don't handle it. Just trying to read a number again won't solve anything.

Comment: Are you aware that your function `isPresent` not only checks if some entries are present in that graph but also completely messes up with the list `adjList[source]` ? Making a copy of `g1` only copies the address of the struct, not the content and linked nodes.

Comment: @Gerhardh Am i modifing it even if i create a tmp list to run the structure? If i wanna read it only to check if the arc is present how can i do? I thought that i had to use the ** to modify it.

Comment: You do not create any temp list. You copy the address of the very same struct in memory to another variable. `gTmp = g1` means that both point to the same location and it does not matter if you do `g1->` or `gTmp->` unless you modify `gTmp` after the initialization.

Comment: To iterate on that list, you could do `node_t*node = g1->adjList[source]; while (node != NULL) { if (node->key == key) {...} node = node->next;}`. That would make a copy of the first pointer in the list and not touch anything in your graph.